# Deseo determinar si un número es primo o compuesto pero no funciona

Tags: c#, números-primos

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Ingrese un número para determinar si es primo o compuesto");

    int i;
    int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    for (i = 2; i < num; i++)
    {
 
    } 
    if (num%i!=0) 
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Es primo");
    }
    else
    { 
      Console.WriteLine("Es compuesto");
    }  
  }
}
```

Dado este código yo quiero determinar si un número es primo o si es compuesto como podrán haber visto, pero siempre que lo pruebo me pone en todos los números que son compuestos. Por qué y como lo arreglo?. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu ciclo for no lo estas utilizando, y para este caso recomiendo mas el uso de una variable boleana

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Ingrese un número para determinar si es primo o compuesto");

    int i;
    int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    bool primo=true;
    for (i = 2; i < num; i++)
    {
       if (num%i==0) {
          primo=false;
          break;
       }
    } 
     if(primo){
      Console.WriteLine("Es primo");  
     }else{
     Console.WriteLine("Es Compuesto");
      }   
     
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero no entiendo algo, para que el break?, Cual es su utilidad?. Además lo probé sin el break y funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del lazo `for` no tienes incluido el código de comprobación, sino que lo tienes fuera del lazo. No te da error de compilación porque la variable `i` la tienes definida antes del `for` y en la primera parte del `for` haces una inicialización de su valor.

Este código te realiza la comprobación.

```
    using System;
                        
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            if (int.TryParse( "123"/*Console.ReadLine()*/, out int input ))
            {
                int num = Math.Abs(input);
                bool isPrime = true;
                
                for (int divisor = 2; divisor < num >> 2; divisor++)
                {
                    if (num % divisor == 0)
                    {
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                Console.WriteLine( isPrime ? $"El número {input} es un número primo" : $"El número {input} no es un número primo");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El texto introducido no es un número entero");
            }
        }
    }
```

Si quieres que tome los datos desde la entrada de consola modifica la línea donde pone `"123"/*Console.ReadLine()*/` y sustituye ese fragmento por `Console.ReadLine()`.